# How to check if last digits in each element of a list are the same

Tags: python

Consider:

```
for g in range(0,len(lst)):
    if lst[g%10] == lst[(g+1)%10]:
```

I am getting an out-of-index error at cards[(i+1)%10]. Why won't this piece of code work? The %10 checks of the last digits in each element of the list are the same.

Comment: `range(len(lst)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
for g in range(len(lst)-1):
    if lst[g%10] == lst[(g+1)%10]:
```

The reason for the `-1` is because you do not have to compare the last value of the list, to the value that comes after it (which is why you're getting the index error, because there are no items that come after the last).

The last item of the list already gets checked when you compare the second to last with the last item.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But now instead of a boolean im getting returned nothing?

Comment: Your original question never mentions a boolean, I have only adjusted the code you pasted in your question.

Comment: Yea sorry, basically in that if statement it just returns True, and then there is an else statement that returns False. Any idea why it returns None when i subtract 1 off the length of the list in the for loop?